# Почему у меня не работает get и выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: javascript

```js
let name = 'Jake'
let sex = 'male'
let age = 30

let person = {
   name,
   sex,
   age,
   greet() {
    console.log(`Hello ${this.name}`);
  },
  get: password() { 
   return this.name + this.age;
  }
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего это легко, но простите новичка

Comment: Что такое `password()` и чего вы пытались этим добиться?

Comment: используешь неверный синтаксис вот и получаешь ошибку

Comment: @Grundy, хорошо, тогда подскажите мне, как его правильно написать, я просто у чувака видео смотрю и у него работает, а у меня как вы поняли нет)))

Comment: @TheDude что вы хотите написать-то? Если вы хотите сделать функцию get, то что вам мешает написать её по аналогии с функцией greet?

Comment: @andreymal, я хочу чтобы при прописании в консоли-person.password, у меня выдавало бы Jack20

Comment: Тогда просто уберите двоеточие

Comment: _я просто у чувака видео смотрю и у него работает_ - сравнивай по символам что написано у него и что написано у тебя